# Adding utterances in the nlu.md file and training a model not working

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

I've added below utterance in the nlu.md file :

```
## intent:input_year
- [2019](year)
```

And have a story like this :

```
## test
* input_year{"year" : "2019"}
 - utter_year
```

The intent `input_year` and action `utter_year` is added to domain.yml

I trained a new model through command line, started rasa x and talked to the bot, on entering `2019` the intent identified is `null0`.

This is my pipeline :

```
pipeline: 
- name: "SpacyNLP"
- name: "SpacyTokenizer"
- name: "RegexFeaturizer"
- name: "SpacyFeaturizer"
- name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
- name: "SklearnIntentClassifier"
- name: "DucklingHTTPExtractor"
  # url of the running duckling server
  url: "http://localhost:8000"
  # dimensions to extract
  dimensions: ["email", "time", "number", "amount-of-money", "distance"]
  # allows you to configure the locale, by default the language is
  # used
  locale: "NL_Nothing"
  # if not set the default timezone of Duckling is going to be used
  # needed to calculate dates from relative expressions like "tomorrow"
  timezone: "US/Pacific"
```

Is this a valid way to train new data ? Or is it important to use the UI to train?
Please suggest what is wrong here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified a entity and slot in domain file if not you have to specify it because if you are defining the intent like this `[2019](year)`. In your case slot will be "year".
You can specify those things like below in your *domain.yml* file.

```
entities:
- echannel_service

slots:
  year:
    type: text
```

Note: Insteat of slot type as text you can use categorical and specifiy the list of years. Refer this about [slots](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/)

If you have already mentioned those things and still it doesnt work, try specifing in the stories like this.

```
## input_year path
* input_year{"yea":"2019"}
    - slot{"year":"2019"}
```

If you don't want to use slots just specify the years in *nlu.md* file like this and try.

```
## intent:input_year
- 2019 year
- 2020 year
```

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1*

hi, you can try adding lookup for your `year` in `nlu.md` like below.

```
## lookup:year
 - 2001
 - 2002
 - 2003
 - 2010
 - 2011
 - 2012
 - 2018
 - 2019
```

*Option 2*

I'm giving this option since you have already trained your bot using interactive form. Try changing your intent like below and check if thats working.

```
## intent:input_year
- [2019](year) year
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: this will just expect '2019 year' to be entered instead of '2019'. still doesn't work though. However, Im not super comfortable with having a lookup for years, can use regex i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Is 2019 the only line you have for that intent? I think Rasa expects several examples for possible inputs per intent. 
Try adding more examples to that intent.

Comment: No I have more, i just mentioned 2019 for brevity